# How to test (using unittest) the HTML output of a Django view?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for my Django application. However, I don't know how to test the HTML output of a view.

Sometimes I might want to check if a specific element contains certain value, or how many of those elements are displayed, or things like that. How can I do such tests?

I would like a solution that uses `unittest` and django's own `django.test`.

I know I can use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Pyccuracy](http://pyccuracy.org/) (which uses Selenium), but Selenium tests are quite slow because of the huge overhead of launching a browser. Also, unit tests work out-of-the-box with [django-coverage](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-coverage/src) package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These other answers are now out of date regarding assertions. The assertion [`assertHTMLEqual`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertHTMLEqual) (since Django 1.4) takes care of things like ignoring whitespace, and ignoring the order of attributes.

For example (from the docs):

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def test_some_html(self):
        # A passing test that doesn't raise an AssertionError.
        self.assertHTMLEqual(
            '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="id_accept_terms" />',
            '<input id="id_accept_terms" type="checkbox" checked>'
        )
```

In practice, one of the arguments to `assertHTMLEqual` would be dynamically generated.

Comment: The links in this post 404

Comment: It's usually better for an answer to show an example instead of a link because said link may be broken in the future and to show code more relevant to the question. In this case, how would you use `assertHTMLEqual` to verify that a DOM element is present (and not having to compare the whole HTML string)?

Comment: @Alechan I don't think this answer is the right solution for you for verifying that  a DOM element is present.  You'd want something that actually builds the DOM in memory, such as Beautiful Soup or lxml -- see Steve Jalim's answer, for example.

Answer (score 14):

I've always found a combination of [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), and assertContains and assertFormError from [TestCase's available assertions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#assertions) to do the trick.

Comment: Or using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) instead of BeautifulSoup. Anyway, it should be easy to write a `assertElementContains` that receives 3 arguments: the response body, a CSS selector and a string.

Answer (score 9):

Django's test framework is ideal for this.

1. Check the status code and content.
   http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.assertContains
2. Check the template.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.assertTemplateUsed

Also, it helps to use `id="something"` tags within your HTML to make it easier to find things when unit testing.  We have tests like this.

```
def should_find_something( self ):
    response= self.client.get( "/path/to/resource/pk/" )
    self.assertContains( response, '<td id="pk">the pk string</td>', status_code=200 )
    self.assertTemplateUsed( response, 'appropriate_page.html' )
```

Works nicely.

Comment: I don't want to check for "Contains", as it will break the test even on whitespace changes. Also, I don't want to write ugly unreadable regexps to match elements.

Comment: The trick is to avoid whitespace in the part that's being tested.  Which is very, very easy to avoid.  `<span id="testing">content</span>` for example, helps in some edge cases.

Comment: No, it's not. It depends a lot on what you are trying to do. Sometimes it's not easy or not possible to avoid whitespace.

Comment: "No, it's not".  Okay.  I've never had a problem with whitespace and have 100's of Django unit tests.  We design our pages for testability.  It's called "Test Driven Development".  We've never had a problem.  If you're having a problem with testability, perhaps you should ask a different question on that subject.

Comment: Okay, your point makes sense. But still... Using `contains` feels wrong, because the element might have multiple classes or some attributes that are not related to the test itself. It also means that smaller design/style changes (like adding or changing classes) might break the test, when it shouldn't.

Comment: Hence the use of `<span id="...">` to narrow the focus on a single testable data element, irrespective of any surrounding tag that may impose a class for style purposes.

Comment: I have problems testing using assertContains exactly because of whitespace - and mangling my templates to avoid whitespace is a horrible workaround.

Comment: @fuzzyman: When whitespace matters, I keep introducing `span id="...">` tags to narrow the focus onto **exactly** the relevant test results.  Happens to me all the time when there's been a small wording change or presentation change to a template.

Comment: This answer should be updated because `assertContains(html=True)` ignores extraneous whitespaces and ignores attribute ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution with BeautifulSoup:

```py
import bs4 as bs


class HtmlTestMixin:
    maxDiff = None

    def assertElementContains(self, request_content, html_element="", html_selectors={}, element_text=""):
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(request_content,  "html.parser")
        element = soup.find(html_element, **html_selectors)
        soup_1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(element_text, "html.parser")
        self.assertEqual(str(element.prettify()), soup_1.prettify())
```

It can be called like:

```py
        self.assertElementContains(
            response.content,
            "select",
            {"id": "order-model"},
            '''
            <select name="order" id="order-model" class="form-select">
                <option value="_score" >
                   Score
                </option>
            </select>
             ''',
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Django with asserts - which uses lxml.

https://django-with-asserts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/